# jQuery - how to show a text box based on a value from a drop down list

Tags: jquery, forms, show-hide

When the page loads I want a `input textbox` to be hidden the id is :amf-input-othertitle_19

But if the the user picks a certain value("other") from a drop down list for that above text box to show so they can fill in the information on that box.

Here's the code dropdown list:

```
<select name="title_3" id="amf-input-title_3">
  <option value="Title" id="title_3-0">Title</option>
  <option value="Mr" id="title_3-1">Mr</option>
  <option value="Mrs" id="title_3-2">Mrs</option>
  <option value="Miss" id="title_3-3">Miss</option>
  <option value="Ms" id="title_3-4">Ms</option>
  <option value="Dr" id="title_3-5">Dr</option>
  <option value="Professor" id="title_3-6">Professor</option>
  <option value="Other" id="title_3-7">Other</option>
```

TextBox to hide/show:

```
<input type="text" class="text" 
  name="othertitle_19" id="amf-input-othertitle_19" 
  value="" placeholder="Please specify other...." 
  maxlength="255" 
  onkeyup="if (this.length>255) this.value=this.value.substr(0, 255)"
  onblur="this.value=this.value.substr(0, 255)"
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#amf-input-othertitle_19').hide(); //Hide on PageLoad

    $('#amf-input-title_3').change(function(){
      if($(this).val() == 'Other'){
         $('#amf-input-othertitle_19').show(); //show if dropdown = other
      }
      else{
        $('#amf-input-othertitle_19').hide(); //hide if changed to something else
      }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
var inp = $('#amf-input-othertitle_19');
$('#mf-input-title_3').change(function () {
    if (this.value == 'other') { //check selected value
        inp.show();
    } else {
        inp.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch the id of the `select` and show it when it's selected

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#amf-input-title_3').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == 'Other') {
            $('#amf-input-othertitle_19').fadeIn(); 
        }
        else{
           $('#amf-input-othertitle_19').fadeOut();
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript:**

```
// Shorthand for $(document).ready(function () { ... });
$(function () {

    // It's more efficient to save off the jQuery object
    // than to re-traverse the DOM each time.
    var $input = $('#amf-input-othertitle_19');

    // Catch the change on <select /> change
    $('#amf-input-title_3').on('change', function () {

        // Quick little ternary operator...
        (this.value === "other") ? $input.show() : $input.hide();
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
// Make sure to hide the input on initial load...
#amf-input-othertitle_19 {
    display: none;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/FC7XT/)